# Troubleshooting with environments and ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, environment

I have been trying to fix the following code but am stuck.

```
library(tidyverse)

piechart <- function(data, mapping) {
  ggplot(data, mapping) +
    geom_bar(width = 1) + 
    coord_polar(theta = "y") + 
    xlab(NULL) + 
    ylab(NULL)
}

piechart3 <- function(data, var, ...) {
  piechart(data, aes_(~factor(1), fill = substitute(var)))
}

f <- function() {
  levs <- c("2seater", "compact", "midsize", "minivan", "pickup", 
            "subcompact", "suv")
  piechart3(mpg, factor(class, levels = levs))
}
f()
```

I get the following response as an error when trying to run f()- "Error in factor(class, levels = levs) : object 'levs' not found". I recognize this is a problem with the environment but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{{}}` which evaluates the unquoted variable as column of the dataframe.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

piechart <- function(data, mapping) {
   ggplot(data, mapping) +
     geom_bar(width = 1) + 
     coord_polar(theta = "y") + 
     xlab(NULL) + 
     ylab(NULL)
}

piechart3 <- function(data, var, ...) {
   piechart(data, aes(factor(1), fill = {{var}}))
}

f <- function() {
  levs <- c("2seater", "compact", "midsize", "minivan", "pickup", 
        "subcompact", "suv")
  mpg$class <- factor(mpg$class, levels = legs)
  piechart3(mpg, class)
}

f()
```

[image]

Comment: When you pass an unquoted variable (`class` here). in function `{{` evaluates it same as you would do `piechart(data, aes(factor(1), fill = class))` outside the function.